# Cannot set iframe size on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova

How can I set the iframe height on ios? Currently it sets the iframe height to the height of the iframe contentDocument, and I cannot change it neither with "height", nor with "position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;" css.

I. e. I see in the safari inspector, that css height is set to "100px" but computed is "12345px" as it is in the iframe.contentDocument.

I tried to create a wrapping div for it, but in this case links on page ain't working (of course, because there's no scrolling in the iframe, so nowhere to scroll)

Is there any solutions?

10x